# C# - Multiple web request at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I want to fetch some data from a web api at same time. so I wrote this code :

```
public string GetData(string x)
{
    try
    {
        string URL = "https://MyApi.com/api?data=" + x;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());

        string res = stuff.Data;

        return res;

     }
     catch (Exception ee)
     {
         throw ee;
     }
}
```

And in my main method I wrote this :

```
try
{
    var tasks = new Task<string>[60];

    for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetData("item" + i.ToString()));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    List<string> Results = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
        Results.Add(tasks[i].Result);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
}
```

So the problem is when I call `GetData()` method Directly (Once), I get my data in less than 1 second. But when I want to simulate to get 60 data at same time using multithreading , it takes more than 7 to 8 seconds. But I want this process takes less than 1 seconds and happen at same time.
And server has no limitation for requesting at same time. (I implemented this code in Android and I had no problem.)

Comment: `WebRequest`is obsolete for 10 years now – use `HttpClient` instead. This would also allow you to make your `GetData` method async so you don’t need to wrap it in an additional CPU bound task and save resources. (Also `Task.Factory.StartNew` without options is also obsolete – use `Task.Run` instead which has better defaults and error handling.) That being said the first request is always slow because it needs to setup things. When you use HttpClient use only one instance for all request, which should hugely improve speeds.

Comment: I've tested it and on my side it takes about half a second to finish all requests (to a hostet server in the internet). So I guess it might have to do with a bandwith limitation on your side? If it works on your android device, it might be that there is another band width limitation than on your pc connection.
Also you are using Tasks that are CPU bound (and ment to be used for processing data). You could get rid of these by using Async-Methods instead of manually creating a Task. Try to get rid of the overhead of creating new instances all the time. Use just one instance and reuse it.

Comment: Oh... seems it took me too long to reproduce :D

Comment: As a side note, you could aggregate the results of all tasks with less code like this: `string[] results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;`. But it's better to use `await` instead of `.Result`.

Comment: Writing `catch (Exception ee) { throw ee; }` is inane and should never coded like that.